# Time Graph in Flot issue?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, flot

I am trying to graph a month out in flot (per day) or possibly every other day, have a tick.

To get my time values, i am doing this:

```
$date = strtotime($rowData[0]); // 2013-01-01
$myData = json_encode(array($date*1000, 1234));
// I Then echo it out as an array into the javascript var.
```

For some reason, i can change the line: `minTickSize: [1, day]` to 2 (label every other tick i think) and nothing will change. Also, the time values are not showing up as well? What am i doing wrong?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xHnDL/)

Here is an update with every two days...is there a rendering issue? Also, why is Oct 10, the only date shown? : [JSFIDDLE UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/xHnDL/1/)

Here is what i have as far as the javascript goes:

```
var myData = [[1380603600000,0],[1380690000000,0],[1380776400000,0],[1380862800000,0],[1380949200000,0],[1381035600000,0],[1381122000000,0],[1381208400000,0],[1381294800000,0],[1381381200000,0],[1381467600000,0],[1381554000000,0],[1381640400000,1],[1381726800000,0],[1381813200000,0],[1381899600000,0],[1381986000000,0],[1382072400000,0],[1382158800000,0],[1382245200000,0],[1382331600000,0],[1382418000000,0],[1382504400000,0],[1382590800000,0],[1382677200000,0],[1382763600000,0],[1382850000000,0],[1382936400000,0],[1383022800000,0],[1383109200000,0],[1383195600000,0]];

var plot = $.plot($(".subsChart"),
   [ { data: myData, label: "myData"} ], {
   series: {
       lines: { show: true,
                lineWidth: 2,
                fill: true, fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.5 }, { opacity: 0.2 } ] }
             },
       points: { show: true, 
                 lineWidth: 2 
             },
       grow: { active: true,
                 steps: 30
             },
       shadowSize: 0
   },
   grid: { hoverable: true, 
           clickable: true, 
           tickColor: "#DDD",
           borderWidth: 1,
           borderColor: "#DDD"
         },
   colors: ["#FF0000"],
    xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%b %m", ticks: myData, minTickSize: [5, "day"]}, 
    yaxis: {ticks:3, tickDecimals: 0},
    tooltip: true,
 });
```

**UPDATE**

> When i remove the `ticks: myData` option, the labels do show up, but all of them are on the same date? Also, none of the points even land on the dates.

Comment: remove the ticks attributes in order to see the ticks. its enough to specify a minTickSize in this case.
xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%b %m", minTickSize: [5, "day"]}

Comment: @Smokie But my dates are off? None of them actually land on a tick. Also, the tick messes up on the far right of the graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Smokie suggested, you need to remove the ticks option.  When you provide ticks, Flot skips any tick generation that it would normally do and uses what you provided instead, which in this case is invalid.

Once you do that, you'll notice that you have labels, but they all show Oct. 10.  That's because your date format is %b (short month name) %m (month number).  I'd guess that what you actually want is %b %d.

Note that you probably won't get a tick for every day because, depending on the size of your window, they wouldn't all fit.  That's why minTickSize is a minimum rather than an exact value; Flot will ensure that at least one day (or however many you specify) separates the ticks, but may choose to spread them out further to ensure that they all fit.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What about the rendering issues i am having? With that tick that is off on the far right.

Comment: Also, what about the label not showing on the first tick? How would i fix that, and the overflow issue of the last label?

Comment: Oh, since 31 can not be evenly divided, it messes everything up...is there a way i can let flot evenly distribute the ticks?

Comment: I tried to mess with different settings, and margins, but i can not figure out how to fix this issue. I even noticed that the label on the far left wont show. I am a bit confused about how flot even does time graphs.

Comment: I took another look, and that appears to be a bug in 0.8.2.  If you revert to 0.8.0 the issue disappears.  Strangely this does not affect any of our test plots; it seems to be related to the number and spacing of your ticks.  We'll get this fixed in 0.8.3.

Comment: Ok, great, and thank for the support. I also noticed when i used `timezone: "browser"` everything was perfect. (But i still will have to check on multiple timezones) @DNS

Comment: See the timezone example: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/axes-time-zones/index.html.  This requires a support library such as date.js.

Comment: hm, ok. That is wierd, since it works without one of those plugins. Ill look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @EliteGamer Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying.  The reason why "browser" timezone works is because Flot by default displays times in UTC.  Your timestamps are in local time, 5 hours behind, which is why the first axis tick got cut off.  By switching it to "browser" your timestamps are displayed in the timezone that you were expecting.

Comment: @EliteGamer Also, we've fixed the issue of the last tick label wrapping; see https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/1283.  This will be released as part of 0.8.3 in the next few days.

Comment: thanks so much. Instead of using the browser timezone, i swapped all the server times to UTC. So it would display well for all visitors.